# How to restrict available parent functions child class users can call

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a `StringIntTable` based on a `HashMap<String, Integer>`.
It's with a single purpose: to produce as a perfect min hash for distinct Strings (each String will have a unique int associated).
Implementation is simple as demonstrated in the code, by extending `HashMap<String, Integer>` and a special `put` method to produce unique integer for each String. In the end the class will have a `String -> int hash` mapping and I can easily query the hash value given a String by `stringIntTable.get("stringValue")`.

However, my concern is that it will work only if callers are only calling the special `put(final String string)` method to add values in. If they call parent `HashMap` functions like `put(K key, V value)` or `putAll`, it would beat the purpose.
Therefore, I'm wondering if there's a way for me to restrict `StringIntTable` users to only call the `put` method but not other similar `HashMap` functions to put new values in?

```java
public class StringIntTable extends HashMap<String, Integer> {
    public int put(final String string) {
        return super.computeIfAbsent(string, v -> super.size() + 1);
    }
}
```

---

One way I can think of, is to use the adapter pattern.
The drawback being that I'll have to provide functions like `lookup()` and `size()`, which are readily available if using previous implementation.

```java
public class StringIntTable {
    private final HashMap<String> stringLookup = new HashMap<>();

    public int put(final String string) {
        return stringLookup.computeIfAbsent(string, v -> stringLookup.size() + 1);
    }

    // Have to write more functions

    public int lookup(final String string) {
        return stringLookup.get(string);
    }

    public int size() {
        return stringLookup.size();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One way I can think of, is to use the adapter pattern.
> The drawback being that I'll have to provide functions like lookup() and size(), which are readily available if using previous implementation.

You have already answered your own question, just replace `#lookup()` with `#get()`.

---

Also, that's not the only way to do this.

All you have to do is either re-write more code, or write more methods.

One way is your `Adapter` -> **write more methods**.

The other way is to reimplement/override the functions from `HashMap.class`. -> **re-write more code**.

I'd rather write more methods than re-write pre-existing code.

If you would like to re-write more code, you have to override (not overload) or rewrite the whole class itself.